# Dreamweaver CC - Export without Markup JavaScript Error (ExtractTemplateXML.js)

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

Whenever I try the "Export without Markup" function, I get this error:

"While executing onClick in ExtractTemplateXML.htm, the following JavaScript error(s) occurred: At line 78 of file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC\Configuration\Commands\ExtractTemplateXML.js": Exception thrown in native function."

It doesn't happen with all sites however. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your relevant code? Please see SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's hundreds of html pages, javascript and css. I'm trying to export mainly all of the html pages without the DW markup.

Comment: Ah, i think i misunderstood you. Is ExtractTemplateXML.htm part of your code?

Comment: No, it's a DW file (code), but that's the only reference it gives in the error message. It appears some file or code in my site causes it to bomb, but it gives no detail as to which of my file(s).

Comment: It should be, but seems like the error is in the dreamweaver itself. Try consulting to adobe on this.